# Set Button Image to Finder Icon

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How would I set a **NSButton's image** to the **Finder icon (programmatically)** ?

I'm trying to do this in **Objective-C/Cocoa** (**Mac**)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's not much point including the icon if I can get it from the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
NSWorkspace *wksp = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSImage *image = [wksp iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kFinderIcon)];
[image setSize:(NSSize){ 128.0f, 128.0f }];
[button setImage:image];
```

You may need to include `<CoreServices/CoreServices.h>` in order for the compiler to know about `kFinderIcon`.

Comment: Yours looks very similar to Wevah's.. any difference in speed or anything?

Comment: @magikseb: Possibly; Wevah's code may be more expensive if it has to look up the exact path to the Finder (and if my code doesn't). I doubt it'll add up to much, but you can time both approaches, running each one a thousand times or something, and see for yourself which one is faster.

Answer (score 9):

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSImage *finderIcon = [workspace iconForFile:[workspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.Finder"]];
[finderIcon setSize:NSMakeSize(128.0, 128.0)];
[yourButton setImage:finderIcon];
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but I get a few errors and a warning... error: expected ',' or ';' before 'NSImage'
error: 'finderIcon' undeclared (first use in this function)
warning: unused variable 'workspace'

Comment: Oh! You were missing a semi-colon after the first line! It now works.

Comment: However: the icon is very small. I had an NSApplication icon (standing in) that was 128x128. Any way I can make the Finder icon bigger?